# How to add a line in XML file using shell with space notation

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, powershell, shell

Hi I have an XML file like this

```
<Parameter name="man" override="false" value="false"/>
<Parameter name="vendor" override="false" value="serve"/>
<Parameter name="buzz" override="false" value=""/>
```

I need to add a line like this

```
<Parameter name="dentist" override="false" value="sunday"/>
```

I need to get the file like this along with the space notation

```
<Parameter name="man" override="false" value="false"/>
<Parameter name="vendor" override="false" value="serve"/>
<Parameter name="dentist" override="false" value="sunday"/>
<Parameter name="buzz" override="false" value=""/>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can check this similar issue : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105569/bash-replace-space-with-new-line

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a well-formed sample XML file, not fragments.

Comment: I just used the sed command to insert the required line but was not able to get the space as it is containing space in front of the line.

Comment: What does "space notation" mean, anyways?

Comment: @RCS : 1. What is your actual question? 2. What is _space notation_?  Why is this tagged _linux_, _bash_ and _powershell_?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), the Swiss Army Knife of command-line XML file manipulation (And an actual XML file based on your sample):

```sh
$ xmlstarlet ed -a '//Parameter[2]' -t elem -n Parameter \
                -i '//Parameter[3]' -t attr -n name -v dentist \
                -i '//Parameter[3]' -t attr -n override -v false \
                -i '//Parameter[3]' -t attr -n value -v sunday input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Parameters>
  <Parameter name="man" override="false" value="false"/>
  <Parameter name="vendor" override="false" value="serve"/>
  <Parameter name="dentist" override="false" value="sunday"/>
  <Parameter name="buzz" override="false" value=""/>
</Parameters>
```

First appends a new `Parameter` node after the second one (Making it the new third one), and then populates it with attributes.